# How can I accomplish string interpolation in solidity?

Tags: solidity

I know I could use abi.encodePacked function to concatenate n number of strings and could accomplish what I want. However, coming from a C# background, I've really come to appreciate the syntactic simplicity of string interpolation. Is there a way to accomplish this in solidity? Something like...

```
uint constant maxValue = 100;

string output = $"Max Value is {maxValue}";
```

Comment: Using strings in solidity is expensive, probably abi.encodePacked is the best thing you can use without resorting to assembly. There's the [solidity string utils library](https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 15th June 2022, in Solidity ^0.8.0, the way you can achieve string interpolation for your code is as follows:

For a number:

```
uint maxValue = 100;
console.log("Max value is %d", maxValue);
```

And for string

```
string name = "Joe"; 
console.log("Hello %s", name);
```